# Что означает количество отзывов от анонимных пользователей и пользователей с низкой репутацией на странице отзывов?

Tags: поддержка, 10k-tools

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/overrated?filter=all

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что вообще эти числа означают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда человек пытается проголосовать, но у нет аккаунта или недостаёт репутации для голоса "за" или "против". Можете открыть данный вопрос в инкогнито и проголосовать и ваш голос тоже, уверен, отобразится в той статистике.

Смысл в том, чтобы узнать как бы голоса перераспределились, если бы все могли голосовать, вне зависимости от репутации и наличия учётной записи.

Comment: А в чём смысл такого голосования?

Comment: @Suvitruf Смысл в том, чтобы узнать как бы голоса перераспределились, если бы все могли голосовать, вне зависимости от репутации и наличия учётной записи.

Comment: Я так понимаю, эта штука по большей части для аналитиков SO.

Comment: @Suvitruf Не уверен, что это так. Мне, к примеру, было бы тоже интересно узнавать эту статистику для каждого поста. Может, я не один такой)

Comment: Просто спрятано слишком глубоко это всё)